# how to compare adjacent values in data dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

how do i get value(i) - value(i-1) (or compare adjacent ) in a data dictionary? I need to flag the adjecent values which are same in the same dictionary

Comment: If your data dictionary is an array or an indexed property, why wouldn't value[i] - values[i-1] work?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are unordered.  There is no position for the items in it, and as a result, there is no such thing as an "adjacent" item.

Answer (score 1):

```
int? lastValue = null;
int diff;
foreach( KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in myDictionary )
{
    if(lastVaue != null) 
        diff = kvp.value - lastValue;
    lastValue = kvp.value;
}
```

As stated by other foreach (GetEnumerator()) is loose in a Dictionary
If you want order you should use another collection.
[OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If the keys are ordered I think you could use
myDictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Key)

Comment: This is not going to be reliable though for repeatable results. When the dictionary goes through a internal resize the `foreach` may reorder the elements.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  Agree.  OP did not define adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you shouldn't be doing this with a regular dictionary.  Adjacency/indexing is not a concept for normal dictionaries.  If you really need something, use an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) which is some sort of hybrid array/dictionary.